# Google App Engine - Memcache - How likely am I to lose data in this scenario?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to store data with every request (what user viewed what page of my site).

With each request I will put the data (~100 bytes) in the memcache.

Every 5 seconds I will persist that data from the memcache to the datastore.

How rare would data loss be in this scenario?

Comment: have you looked at using something like Google Analytics to track this data?

Comment: @matt b Yea, I thought about that, I would need to be able to download all of the analytics data and process it though.  Do you know if I can download the data in bulk, and programmatically?  I need to show the number of users who viewed the page on the page.

Comment: there's a "Data Export API", take a look at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically can't trust memcache to keep your data *at all*. It's just a cache, after all, and can choose to evict data whenever it feels it is nessecary.

Having said that, in your particular scenario, the worst that will happen is you will lose 5 seconds worth of data. I don't think that's a big deal if you're just storing "pageview" data. Besides, unless the cache is running out of memory, there's really no need for it to evict data and so it's probably going to be fairly rare.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how heavily your app uses memcache for other things. Instead of this approach, though, I would suggest using [task queues](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) to store the data to the datastore for each request, without slowing the user-facing request down.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust memcached to remember your things for later.  If you want something persisted then persist it there and then.